# while accessing column i got row in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am accessing column values but it gives me the row values while indexing 2-d array in numpy.

> The general format is `arr_2d[row][col]` or `arr_2d[row,col]`. recommended
>   is comma notation for clarity

```
arr_2d = np.arange(0,9).reshape((3,3))

# sub array
arr_2d[0:2,1:]

arr_2d[:,0] # in row form but the data will be of the column.
```

> access column data but it gives me row values.

```
 arr_2d[:][0] # it gives the first row data.
```

> **What is the difference between comma notation and bracket notation?**

Comment: Look at the effect of each bracket. What does `x[:]` do?  The colon isn't placeholder for the next [4].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr_2d[row][col]` is only works as you intended, i.e, like `arr_2d[row,col]`, if you pass an integer as `row` index, not `slices`.
For e.g.:

```
>>> arr_2d = np.arange(0,9).reshape((3,3))
>>> arr_2d[1][2]
5
>>> arr_2d[1,2]
5
```

But:

```
>>> arr_2d[:][2]
array([6, 7, 8])
```

This is because `np.ndarray[:]` is essentially a copy of the original array:

```
>>> arr_2d[:]
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> arr_2d
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

and:

```
>>> arr_2d[2]
array([6, 7, 8])
# so no surprises here:
>>> arr_2d[:][2]
array([6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

The notation `arr_2d[:,0]` translates to select all items in dimension 0, and the the first item in dimension 1 - amounting to the entire first column (item 0 of all rows).

The notation `arr_2d[:][0]` is chaining two operations:

1. `arr_2d[:]`means select all items in dimension 0 - basically referring to the entire matrix.
2. [0] simply selects the first item in the matrix returned by the first operation - returning the first row.

In order to select the first row, you can use either `arr_2d[0]` or more 'verbosely' `arr_2d[0, :]` (which translates to "all columns of the first row").

You could access the same items using both notations, but in different ways. For example - 
In order to select the 3rd item in the 2nd row you could use:

1. Comma notation - `arr_2d[1, 2]`
2. Bracket notation - `arr_2d[1][2]`

Comment: while learning it tells that the bracket notation and comma notation is the same. but the bracket is recommended, but it behaves differently

Comment: You can achieve the same result using both notations, but their use is not identical... i'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: please use bracket notation and access the column

Comment: For the purpose of selecting a column I think the only (easy) way would be using the comma notation.